# Sign extension operations support is not enabled

Tags: ink, flipper

I am running through https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/smart-contracts/prepare-your-first-contract/#deploy-the-contract and hitting an issue when deploying the flipper ink! contract with this log message from the node:

`DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker runtime::contracts: sign extension operations support is not enabled (at offset 0x1efd)`

I am using the following:

`substrate-contracts-node version 0.23.0-87a3d76c880`

`cargo-contract 1.5.1-unknown-aarch64-apple-darwin`

I generated the contract with:
`cargo contract new flipper`

and the contract WASM with:
`cargo +nightly contract build`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like adding `--optimization-passes=0` sorted this out when building the contract